# How to enable occlusion with shadow catcher in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, shadowcatcher

I am using Blender 2.92.

I have a shadow catcher in my scene,
that I would like to also occlude objects between 
him and the light source.

for example please observe the following result:

[image]

The shadow inside the box should not be rendered as it is occluded by the outer wall of the shadow cathcer itself,

I have also tried to place a cube between the one in the scene and the shadow catcher but it doesnt change the occlusion.


Here is my scene in plane view:
[image]

Does anyone have any idea how to approach this? I don't mind using composition or any other method etc.